# Определение четных и нечетных свойств в обьекте при помощи цикла FOR...IN

Tags: javascript

буду благодарен любым объяснениям и помощи.Не понимаю структуру переменной которая перебирает свойства window .

---

Задание:
Распечатать все свойства объекта window. Выводить каждое свойство с новой строки, чередуя цвет выводимых свойств: черный | синий.
Рекомендации:   Использовать дополнительную переменную для проверки четности.
Использовать условный оператор If.

```js
for (let prop in window)
{
    document.write(prop + "<br>");
}
```

[image: Распечатать все свойства объекта window. Выводить каждое свойство с новой строки, чередуя цвет выводимых свойств: черный | синий. Рекомендации: Использовать дополнительную переменную для проверки четности. Использовать условный оператор If.]

Comment: "*Не понимаю структуру переменной которая перебирает свойства window .*" --- что это значит? и как оно соотносится с чётностью/нечётностью?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможно неправильно сформулировал вопрос, как обращаться к свойствам переменной которая перебирает свойства объекта window , т.к.  свойства объекта строковые , и я не могу понять как  сделать  цикл  чтобы определить четное и нечетное значение каждого свойства.

Comment: А задание прочитать? "Рекомендации: Использовать дополнительную переменную для проверки четности." Четность не свойства, а порядкового номера, под которым оно выводится.

Comment: Добавьте переменную вне вашего for и каждую итерацию увеличивайте. Вот вам и счетчик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let i = "0"
for(let prop in window) {
     i++

     if(i%2 ===0) {
          document.write("<font color='blue'>"+prop+"</font>"+'</br>')
      }    
       else  {
         document.write(prop+"</br>")}
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let even = true;
for (let prop in window) {
    if (even) color = "black"; else color = "blue";
    document.write(`<span style="color:${color}">${prop}</span><br>`);
    even = !even;
}
```

Comment: в задаче сказано, что нужно использовать If